# How can we handle dupes in a merged dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to merge two dataframes and I'm struggling to get this setup right. I Googled for a solution before posting here, but I'm still stuck. This is what I'm working with.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# Intitialise data of lists
data1 = [{'ID': 577878, 'Year':2020, 'Type': 'IB', 'Expense':6500}, 
         {'ID': 577878, 'Year':2019, 'Type': 'IB', 'Expense':16500}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1

data2 = [{'ID': 577878, 'Year':2020, 'Type': 'IB', 'Expense':23000}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2


df_final = pd.merge(df1, 
          df2,
          left_on=['ID'],
          right_on=['ID'],
          how='inner')
df_final
```

[image]

This makes sense, but I don't want the 23000 duplicated.

If I do the merge like this.

```
df_final = pd.merge(df1, 
          df2,
          left_on=['ID','Year'],
          right_on=['ID','Year'],
          how='inner')
df_final
```

[image]

This also makes sense, but now the 16500 is dropped off because there is no 2019 in df2.

How can I keep both records, but not duplicate the 23000?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I don't understand why your merge this 2 dataframe if the only column that differs is dropped?

Comment: Have you tried an outer join on ID only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation is that you just don't want to see 2 entries of 23000 for both 2019 and 2020.  It should be for 2020 only.

You can use outer merge (with parameter `how='outer'`) on 2 columns `ID` and `Year`, as follows:

```
df_final =  pd.merge(df1, 
                     df2,
                     on=['ID','Year'],
                     how='outer')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_final)

       ID  Year Type_x  Expense_x Type_y  Expense_y
0  577878  2020     IB       6500     IB    23000.0
1  577878  2019     IB      16500    NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Yeah, SeaBean, this seems to do it. I thought I tried 'outer' before I posted my question, but I guess something was off there. I know inner, left, and right. I thought I knew outer. Can you explain how your solution works?

Comment: @ASH You can refer to the official Pandas document that outer merge uses union of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL full outer join. As it is union of keys, you will see rows from both dataframes even for rows not matching completely the merge key.  It is by this way that we can still show the row of year 2019 even when there is no 2019 in df2. The non matching fields eg. Expense_y will show as `NaN` as there is no data from df2 for this row.  In this way, you will not see duplicate entry of 23000 in irrelevant row.

Answer (score 1):

Try, column filter the `df2` not to merge in that column:

```
df1.merge(df2[['ID', 'Year', 'Type']], on=['ID'])
```

Output:

```
       ID  Year_x Type_x  Expense  Year_y Type_y
0  577878    2020     IB     6500    2020     IB
1  577878    2019     IB    16500    2020     IB
```